# си arduino парсинг строки

Tags: android, c, массивы, arduino

от мобильного приложения по блютуз  получаю строчку вида ab123zaf333zaf143zaf153zab163z

где a - начало посылки, b123 - (b команда (char)) (123 - данные (int)), z - окончание посылки

ардуинка должна принимать строку и печатать в терминал
b123 f333 f143 но печатаются рандомные значения

```js
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(4, 3); // RX | TX  7.6


char incoming[4]; //массив считанных данных

char value[3]; //массив считанных данных

char command;  //адресат данных
int i = 0;
char d;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter commands:");
  BTSerial.begin(38400);  // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
}

void loop()
{

  char data;
  
  if (BTSerial.available())


    if ( String(BTSerial.read()) = "a")
    {


      d = BTSerial.read();
      
      for (int q = 1; q < 3; q++)

        { data = BTSerial.read();
     
            if ( String(data) != "z")
            {
              incoming[q] = data;
            }
      
            else if  (String(data) = "z"){  
              break;
            }
      }

       sscanf(incoming, "%d", &i); //преобразование массива  в число i
          Serial.println(i); //вывод данных 
    Serial.println(d); //вывод данных
    }

  
 

}
```

что я сделал не так

Comment: Что это за язык вообще? Почему на вопросе стоит тэг [C]? Это больше похоже на С++, но `if  (String(data) = "z")` наводит на сомнения... Сравнение на равенство и в С, и в С++ всегда было `==`, а не `=`.

Comment: @AnT это плюсы с ардуиновской либой...  но код, конечно, оставляет желать лучшего...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ошибка в операторе присвоить (=) вместо оператора сравнить (==):

```
if ( String(BTSerial.read()) == 'a')

else if  (String(data) == 'z'){
```

Также в языке C есть разница между сравнением с символьной константой ('a') и адресом строчной константы в памяти ("a").

```
if ( String(data) != 'z')
```